# Syntax Error :can't assign to function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is my code below

```
plt.figure(1), plt.subplot(121), df=train.dropna(),
sns.distplot(df['LoanAmount'])
```

I am getting an error like this

```
> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: Are they comma separated in your real code?

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with the code, but I will point out the major points:

```
plt.figure(1), plt.subplot(121), df=train.dropna(), sns.distplot(df['LoanAmount'])
```

The commas are interpreted as the line being a tuple, with the equals indicating left and right hand sides, in the same way that

```
x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
```

Would be, i.e.:

```
plt.figure(1), plt.subplot(121), df =
    train.dropna(), sns.distplot(df['LoanAmount'])
```

.  What you probably meant was

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(121)
df = train.dropna()
sns.distplot(df['LoanAmount'])
```

which you could write (not advisable) as

```
plt.figure(1); plt.subplot(121); df=train.dropna(); sns.distplot(df['LoanAmount'])
```

The main error you see is correct, you can't have a line like

```
a() = b
```

That assigns to a function call (it would have no meaning), which you do in the original interpretation.

Comment: Good explanation :)